# fread and fwrite in c adding and subtracting bytes from file1 to file2

Tags: c, file, io, arrays

I have a file `file1` and I need to create a new file by changing some bytes from `file1`.

I need to keep the first `n` bytes and transfer it to `file2`. I can do that by making an array x[n] then using `fwrite`.

The problem is for the bytes after that I need to subtract two bytes and then divide and then write it to the new file. I don't know how many bytes the file contains so I don't know how big my array should be.

And what would be an efficient way of adding and subtracting bytes using `fread`.

Answer (score 0):

> I dont know how many bytes the file contains so I don't know how big my array should be.

use `fstat` to ask the system how big the file is.